# How to pass an Intent string to an XML widget in a new activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

I am following the tutorials for "building your first app" at developer.android.com, and have a question about how to pass information between activities and XML layouts.

I have a layout for each activity:

[Here are pictures of the layouts I am using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CQ1w.jpg)
The one on the left is the main activity, while the one on the right is the secondary activity that is started when the "send" button is pressed.

I want the app to pass a message input to the EditText widget in the main activity to a TextView in the secondary activity while maintaining  the picture and background formatting I currently have for the secondary activity.

The "starting another activity" section of the "building your first app" tutorial on the developer.android site only shows how to have the message passed to the secondary activity with a TextView defined in java, while disregarding the XML layout.

How do I get the message to forward to my XML layout, or how can I incorporate both a TextView defined in java, along with an XML layout?

[Here is all my code for the activities' XML and JAVA files](http://pastebin.com/70jeyKYR)
Sorry for the huge dump, but this site will not let me post more than two links right now

I tried referring to the secondary activity's TextView in that activities java file, and then setting the text from there, but my program crashes when I do that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making a brand new `TextView` in your second activity:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
```

you should instead give the `TextView` element in your second activity layout file an id:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/yellow"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:text="message" />

    <ImageView
       android:src="@drawable/open"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can then reference this very same `TextView` in the code of your second activity *after* the content view is set:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // must call this after setting the content view;
    // otherwise, textView will still be null.
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```